# Создать пакетный файл, который во всех файлах папки заменит символы

Tags: файлы, cmd, bat

Добрый день!

Пытался создать пакетный файл, который во всех файлах в папке заменит букву t на букву s. Вот мой код: `for /r c:\ %%i in (*t*.*) do ren %%i (*s*.*)`

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Всё не так. Вот как надо:

```
rem Включаем отложенное расширение переменных
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Цикл по всем файлам, содержащих в именах букву t (с заходом в подкаталоги)
for /r c:\ %%i in (*t*.*) do (
    rem Выделяем имя файла (без каталога и расширения).
    set NEW_NAME=%%~ni

    rem Заменяем все вхождения буквы t на s.
    set NEW_NAME=!NEW_NAME:t=s!

    rem Переименовываем исходный файл. Новое имя гененрируем из переменной
    rem !NEW_NAME!, добавляя к ней исходное расширение (%%~xi).
    rename "%%i" "!NEW_NAME!%%~xi"
)

EndLocal
```

Более подробно о применённых конструкциях можно узнать в справке, выводимой следующими командами:

```
SetLocal /?
set /?
for /?
```